# reversing an image gradient transformation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, gradient

I have this function in matlab where a grayscaled image is converted to an image gradient. What i'm wondering is if there is a way to take the image I got here (gradient) and convert it back to the grayscale image (im_gray) such that input_grayscale == output_grayscale

```
function gradient = gradient_conv(im_gray)

wx=[1, -1];
wy=[1, -1]';

image=im2double(im_gray);

image_gradx=imfilter(double(image),wx,'conv','replicate');
image_grady=imfilter(double(image),wy,'conv','replicate');
G1=sqrt(image_gradx.^2+image_grady.^2);
G1=double(G1*255);

A=max(max(G1));
G1=G1/A;
gradient=uint8(G1*255);
end
```

Comment: The inverse of a gradient, which is differentiation, is integration.

Comment: The problem is that you use the _magnitude_ of the gradient. You can recover an image from its gradient, but not from the magnitude of the gradient